# Is there a more elegant way to check if a String is a valid Int in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, jvm

This is Kotlin/JVM

I currently have this code :

```kotlin
fun String.isValidInt(): Boolean {
    var isInt: Boolean = false
    try {
        if (this.toInt().toString() == this) {
            isInt = true
        } 
    } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
        isInt = false
    }
    return isInt
}
```

and I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to approach this, specficially the way I set the return value `isInt` to true or false.

[Here](https://pl.kotl.in/vehCohwry) is a playground link to my code and a main function to test with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start, `try` can return an expression.  Together with using the expression form of the function body, removing the redundant `if` and `this`, and avoiding the local variable, it becomes:

```
fun String.isValidInt()
    = try {
        toInt().toString() == this
    } catch (x: NumberFormatException) {
        false
    }
```

However, that still unnecessarily creates a String object.

There's a [`toIntOrNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int-or-null.html) function which would make it simpler and more efficient:

```
fun String.isValidInt() = toIntOrNull() != null
```

Note that in all these cases it's actually performing the conversion (and discarding the result).  In most cases, I'd expect you want to use the result, so you may be better off having your code call `toIntOrNull()` directly.

Comment: Thank you, this works great. It was more of a proof of concept than anything but I was curious if there was a way to make it better.