# Kotlin: check if string is numeric

Tags: kotlin

Is there a simple way to check if user's input is numeric? Using regexes and exceptions seems too complicated here.

```
fun main {
    val scan = Scanner(System.`in`)
    val input = scanner.nextLine()
    if (!input.isNumeric) {
        println("You should enter a number!")
    }
}
```

Comment: I've found one way to check if input is integer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48116753 but that doesn't answer my question fully. It's writing own function:

`fun isInteger(str: String?) = str?.toIntOrNull()?.let { true } ?: false`

Comment: `String.toIntOrNull()` is probably the simplest way to do this check, because it hides the exception check if the conversion fails and gives you an int if it could be converted or null if it couldn't. So the function you noted is totally valid.

Comment: Just use `str?.toIntOrNull() != null`. Using let is confusing.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65282335

Comment: Yes, thank you all. But that's only for Int. How should doubles and floats handled?

Comment: "How should doubles and floats handled?" `toDoubleOrNull()` will cover all of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method mentioned above will work for a `number <= approximately 4*10^18` essentially max limit of `Double`.

Instead of doing that since `String` itself is a CharSequence, you can check if all the character belong to a specific range.

```kotlin
val integerChars = '0'..'9'

fun isNumber(input: String): Boolean {
    var dotOccurred = 0
    return input.all { it in integerChars || it == '.' && dotOccurred++ < 1 }
}

fun isInteger(input: String) = input.all { it in integerChars }

fun main() {
    val input = readLine()!!
    println("isNumber: ${isNumber(input)}")
    println("isInteger: ${isInteger(input)}")
}
```

Examples:

```kotlin
100234
isNumber: true
isInteger: true

235.22
isNumber: true
isInteger: false

102948012120948129049012849102841209849018
isNumber: true
isInteger: true

a
isNumber: false
isInteger: false
```

Its efficient as well, there's no memory allocations and returns as soon as any non-satisfying condition is found.

You can also include check for negative numbers by just changing the logic if hyphen is first letter you can apply the condition for `subSequence(1, length)` skipping the first character.

Comment: So as a general rule, don't mention "above" in an answer; answer order changes when your answer is accepted or upvoted ;)

Comment: With this solution, "." returns true for isNumber.

Comment: @nayriz Technically `0 == 0. == .0 == . == 0.0 == 0.00 == .00 etc` (not taking significant figures into account), also calculator on my android assumes `.` as 0, `.x6=0` `x-6=-6` etc...

Answer (score 7):

Simply use : `text.isDigitsOnly()` in **kotlin**.

Comment: This doesn't work for Float/Double: `"1.123".isDigitsOnly() == false`

Answer (score 6):

joining all the useful comments and putting it in a input stream context, you can use this for example:

```
fun readLn() = readLine()!!
fun readNumericOnly() {
    println("Enter a number")
    readLn().toDoubleOrNull()?.let { userInputAsDouble ->
        println("user input as a Double $userInputAsDouble")
        println("user input as an Int ${userInputAsDouble.toInt()}")
    } ?: print("Not a number")


}
readNumericOnly()
```

for input: 10

```
user input as a Double 10.0 
user input as an Int 10
```

for input: 0.1

```
user input as a Double 0.1 
user input as an Int 0
```

for input: "word"

```
Not a number
```

Answer (score 1):

Well all the answers here are best suited for their own scenarios:
But not all string are numeric digits it can have (-) and (.) decimal pointers.

So to accomplish this I made a cocktail of all the answers suggested below and from other posts as well which - looks like below :

```
fun isPosOrNegNumber(s: String?) : Boolean {
    return if (s.isNullOrEmpty()) false 
    else{
        if(s.first()=='-' && s.filter { it == '.' }.count() <= 1) {
            s.removeRange(0,1).replace(".","").all{Character.isDigit(it)}
        }
        else s.all {Character.isDigit(it)}
    }
}
```

Above code does a good job for its purpose.
But then it struck me kotlin does an even better job with matching a regex and voila the solution became simple and elegant as below :

```
fun isPosOrNegNumber(s: String?) : Boolean {
    val regex = """^(-)?[0-9]{0,}((\.){1}[0-9]{1,}){0,1}$""".toRegex()
    return if (s.isNullOrEmpty()) false 
           else regex.matches(s)
        
}
```

This sample regex is only for US number formats but if you want to use EU number formats then just replace '.' with ','

Bdw. if the numbers contain commas then just replace it while sending to this method or better form a regex pattern with commas in it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way to check if the given string is numeric( to check for both negative and positive values ) or not:

```
val intChars =  '0'..'9'


fun isNumeric(input: String) = input
    .removePrefix("-")
    .all { it in '0'..'9' }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer without any custom functions is to utilise `toDoubleOrNull` function. If it returns null, the string is not numeric.

```kotlin
val string = "-12345.666"
if (string.toDoubleOrNull()!=null) // string is numeric
{
  //do something
}
```

If you know the input only contains integers you can also use `toIntOrNull` likewise